# NullPointerException when using customized Autowired

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, autowired, spring-aop

I customized a Annotation @CustomizedAutowired like @Autowired by using BeanPostProcessor (InjectBeanPostProcessor.java), but I got a NullPointerException when AOP is used.

1. Why it is null when using AOP?
2. Why DemoController seems to be proxied twice when using AOP?
3. what should I do, so that @CustomizedAutowired can work just like @Autowired?

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
public @interface CustomizedAutowired {}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class DemoController {

    @CustomizedAutowired
    private InjectBean injectBean;

    @GetMapping("/world")
    public LocalDateTime hello() {
        injectBean.hello(); // injectBean is null
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AopDemo {

    @Pointcut("execution(public java.time.LocalDateTime *(..))")
    public void pointcut() {}

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "pointcut()")
    public void round() {
        System.out.println("after returning");
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class InjectBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class<?> targetClass = bean.getClass();
        while (targetClass != null) {
            Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(CustomizedAutowired.class)) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        field.set(bean, new InjectBean());
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            targetClass = targetClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @CustomizedAutowired
    private InjectBean injectBean;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("instance -> " + this);
        injectBean.hello(); // works fine here
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: IDE screenshot]

Comment: This question is still listed as unanswered, even though it has two answers. I hope you can accept and upvote my answer. Please do not just leave the question open, even though your problem is solved already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `field.set(bean, new InjectBean())` on the proxy bean, because it does not inherit any private fields. You need to unwrap the proxy and set the field on the original object.

I am not going to comment on the idea of using all that ugly reflection in order to implement your custom injection idea, just help you make it work. You can use `AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(bean)` instead of your while-loop in order to get the original object and then easily its class afterwards.

How about this?

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70408968;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@Component
public class InjectBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    // Unwrap bean, in case it is a proxy
    Object targetObject = AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(bean);
    Class<?> targetClass = targetObject.getClass();
    Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
      if (field.isAnnotationPresent(CustomizedAutowired.class)) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
          field.set(targetObject, new InjectBean());
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return bean;
  }
}
```

This is going to work both with and without AOP proxies. Note how I am injecting the field into `targetObject`, but returning the original `bean` instance (i.e. the proxy in the AOP case).

Then, get rid of the annotated member in the application class, because the application is not a normal Spring component.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70408968;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      context.getBean(DemoController.class).hello();
    }
  }
}
```

Now the application runs just fine.

```
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
d.s.spring.q70408968.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 7.457 seconds (JVM running for 10.318)
Hello from InjectBean
after returning
```

---

Or maybe you prefer a Java streams approach, but that is just cosmetics:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70408968;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
public class InjectBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    // Unwrap bean, in case it is a proxy
    Object targetObject = AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(bean);
    Arrays.stream(targetObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
      .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(CustomizedAutowired.class))
      .forEach(field -> {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
          field.set(targetObject, new InjectBean());
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      });
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using AopTestUtils. getTargetObject(bean) is a good idea and it works fine for me, Thanks.

Comment: It is also not difficult to unwrap the proxy by yourself by checking for `instanceof Advised`, then casting if so, then calling `getTargetSource().getTarget()` and `getTargetSource().getTargetClass()`. But I wanted to keep it simple and see if the dependency on the test utils is OK for you.

Comment: BTW, the best way to thank me is to accept and upvote my answer. Your own answer uses a different approach you did not ask for, and I already told you that the target object for `postProcessAfterInitialization` is a proxy which needs to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

After searching from google, I found that the reason why NPE happens is that we got the wrong targetObject, `BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)` gives us a proxied bean, and if we use AOP, it will be proxied twice, replace  `postProcessAfterInitialization` with `postProcessBeforeInitialization` can solve this problem, or another solution that can do the Injection Operation before being proxied by AOP.